# negative value of signals

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, time-domain

[image: here is a sample signal]
can we say there is no sound produced when the amplitude is 0?
if yes what can we say when the amplitude is negative?

Comment: Short answer: it means your signal is either zero or negative. If you really want a meaningful answer, you should add more information about the source/ nature of your signal and why you have troubles interpreting the observed behavior

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are talking about soundwaves only, so I'll approach the answer from there.

The instant values a signal takes don't tell much about the sound it may generate. If a signal is zero at a certain instant $t_0$, it doesn't mean that at that moment there is silence. A single sample can't represent any sound because only oscillations can generate sound. I hope you see why a single sample can't possibly represent  an oscillation of any kind.

Take for example a perfect sinewave. The signal $x(t)=\sin(t)$ is $0$ for infinite values of $t$, but the sound you hear is nonetheless uniform and constant. Also, it takes both positive and negative values, but the note you hear is always the same.

If a signal is $0$ for a given period of time though, then for that interval there will be silence indeed. In fact, if a signal is *constant* for a given period of time (not necessarily $0$), you will hear no sound at all (but you would be wasting power nonsensically).

In a nutshell, the instant values of a signal represent no sound whatsoever. It's the *change over time* of these values that can represent and generate sounds.

Comment: what if our signal is negative for a given period of time

Comment: @ar4nm3t As long as it is varying, there will be sound. Whether it is negative or positive doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Truthfully, the zero isn't really zero at all, just a relative value.

When an audio signal is recorded, the signal values represent variations in air pressure around a central average value.

When an audio signal is played back, the zero represents the resting position of the speaker cone.

When a signal as no ampitude (all samples are zero) then there is no sound.  An individual sample (as already pointed out) is meaningless in this context.  However, a DC signal (all samples the same value) will not make a sound either.  (With coupling capacitors, the speaker cone will return to resting position, but that is a different story).

Ced